# Return only a part of the match

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string, search

Here's an example http://jsbin.com/USONirAn/1

```
var string = "some text username#Jake#  some text username#John# some text some text username#Johny# userphoto#1.jpg#";

var type = "username";
var regexp = new RegExp(type + "#(.*?)#");
var matches = string.match(regexp);
```

Current regexp returns into `matches` an array with 3 items - `[username#Jake#, username#John#, username#Johny#]`.

How do I make it return only a strings that I used to search for - `(.*?)`? In this example is should be an array `[Jake, John, Johny]`. Is it possible to get this only by changing a regexp function?

Update:
I've also tried to use `exec` function, but it returns both `[username#Jake#, Jake]`  http://jsbin.com/USONirAn/6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search-and-don't-replace

```
var matches = []
string.replace(regexp, function () {
    matches.push(arguments[1]);
});
```

http://jsbin.com/USONirAn/4

Comment: I like your solution, but I wonder if there's a shorten solution available on this question. Yours uses 3 functions for a single match and the arguments[1], which can't be minified.

Comment: minified arguments:`function (a,b) {matches.push(b)});`